# Filtering between cells with specific characters in R

Tags: r

I'm importing a number of scripts into R from the language analysis software CLAN. CLAN scripts start with some information about the data in the script, and finish with some quantification of the data. In between this there is a list of words.

So I have something like this:

n <-

```
n       word         filename
Wed      Aug          010427 
freq    (01-Aug-2018) 010427 
ONLY    speaker       010427
******  NA            010427
From    file          010427
Speaker:*MOT:         010427
1        Al           010427
13       Alex         010427
1        Alex's       010427
2        Bert         010427
----     NA           010427
544                   010427
```

I want to extract all of the data between the rows where `n == "Speaker:"` and `n == "----"`. This will be the same for each of my files. For these rows, `word = NA` at both points, too.

I've tried using `dplyr::filter(ifelse(word %in% "Speaker:":"-----"))` but perhaps needless to say, that won't work. Any other suggestions very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're attempted solution used `dplyr` here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>% mutate(keep = if_else(n == 'Speaker:',T,NA),
              keep = if_else(n == '----',F,keep)) %>%
       fill(keep, .direction='down') %>%
       filter(n != 'Speaker:', keep ==T)
```

First it creates a column flagging whether data should be kept (T/F), keeping data starting with 'Speaker:' and ending with '----'. It then filters out the data we don't flag as keep, along with the 'Speaker:' row itself.

Comment: @CatherineLaing please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest making a new column that will indicate if the row is between "Speaker" and "----". This column should be 1 if it is between and 0 if not!

```
df$is_in <- 0
df$is_in[df$n == "Speaker"] <- 1
df$is_in[df$n == "----"] <- -1 
df$is_in <- cumsum(df$is_in)  # that way it will jump to 1 when "speaker" and to 0 when "----"

df[as.logical(df$is_in),]  # will only select you the rows where "is_in" is 1!
```

Getting rid of the rows that still include "Speaker" is simply done by `df <- df[df$n != "Speaker", ]`.

*Comment: This solution suggests that "Speaker" and "----" occur multiple times in your dataframe, which I assume given that you have a column with your filename*

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've successfully imported it as a data frame:

```
first_row = which(your_data$n == "Speaker:")
last_row = which(your_data$n == "-----")
result = your_data[first_row:last_row, ]
```

You can use `(first_row + 1):(last_row - 1)` if you don't want those rows included in the result.

Unlike tobiaspk1's more general answer, this will only work if the "Speaker" and "-----" rows are unique.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work but I guess that's because the rows aren't unique in this case, but this would be a neat option for another dataset!

Answer (score 0):

A variation:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(row_number() > which(n == "Speaker:") & row_number() < which(n == "----"))
#   n     word   filename
# 1 1     Al     010427  
# 2 13    Alex   010427  
# 3 1     Alex's 010427  
# 4 2     Bert   010427
```